# Postfix - How to alias some user@host.com to another user, but only for certain values of "host.com"?

Tags: email, postfix, alias, forwarding

I have a Postfix email setup. It's handle a few domains (i.e. I have them in my `mynetworks` in my `main.cf`). I have a normal unix account and use that to log in, and get my mail. My personal email account is of the form user@personal.com. I have a new domain new.com, and I want to forward info@new.com to user@personal.com, however I don't want to forward info@personal.com.

Someone has suggested just forwarding all 'info' to 'user', and then using procmail on my user@ account to remove the info@personal.com

The server is Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/etc/postfix/virtual` files to define individual email address mappings. For this to work, you need two more lines in `main.cf`:

```
virtual_alias_domains = new.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Now add a line like

```
info@new.com user@personal.com
```

to `/etc/postfix/virtual` then run

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

and restart Postfix.